# Calendly change language

Tags: javascript, calendly

We have a multilingual website & I would like to change calendly language programatically.
Is there a language parameter I can pass?

```
Calendly.initInlineWidget({
            url: 'https://calendly.com/testuser/test',
        });
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There is unfortunately not currently a way to programmatically change the language with a parameter, but you can create a new event type and change the language setting for that new event type. Then you could load that new event type based on your websites language.

You can change the invitee language using this link in the upper left corner, when creating a new event_type.

Here's a screenshot: [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DE0yu.png)